# How to handle an event of a child element, on a parent element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, fluentui-react

I have a component that contains a `Checkbox` component from the `@fluentui/react-components` library, and I am using an `onChange` event on the `Checkbox` component.

```
const ContactText = ({ contact, contactKey, selectedContacts, setSelectedContacts }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={contactIcon} alt="Contact Icon" />
      <div>
        <Checkbox
          labelPosition="before"
          label={`${contact.firstname} ${contact.surname}`}
          checked={selectedContacts.filter((contact) => contact.key == contactKey).checked}
          //@ts-ignore - Ignore event parameter on onChange
          onChange={(event, data) => {
            setSelectedContacts((prevState: SelectedContactModel[]) =>
              data.checked
                ? [
                    ...prevState,
                    {
                      key: contactKey,
                      checked: data.checked,
                      companyKey: contact.companyKey,
                      companyName: contact.companyName,
                      individual: contact.individual,
                      title: contact.title,
                      firstname: contact.firstname,
                      surname: contact.surname,
                      telephone: contact.telephone,
                      mobile: contact.mobile,
                      retired: contact.retired,
                      address: contact.address,
                      postcode: contact.postcode,
                      email: contact.email,
                    },
                  ]
                : prevState.filter((contact) => contact.key !== contactKey)
            );
          }}
        />
        {contact.email != "" ? <SecondaryText text={contact.email} /> : <></>}
        {contact.telephone != "" ? <TertiaryText text={contact.telephone} /> : <></>}
        {contact.mobile != "" ? <TertiaryText text={contact.mobile} /> : <></>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I want to have the onChange to happen when I click the outermost div of the ContactText component. I have seen people using `useRef` although I am wondering if there are different ways of doing this.

Comment: Look into `useImperativeHandle`

Comment: I saw this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456604/how-to-call-a-child-method-on-parent-events-with-react Would this be a solution I could take?

Comment: That's exactly what you need. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60484449/2891356) (the updated with hooks portion)

Comment: Don't forget that you can also declare the `onChange` handler in your parent component and just pass it down as a prop to your `ComtactText` and then pass that to `CheckBox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [@Mike K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77861712/12100054) and [another answer I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60484449/12100054), this is what I came up with. This lets me call `onChange` from the div element outside of the Checkbox element.

```
const ContactText = React.forwardRef(
  ({ contact, contactKey, selectedContacts, setSelectedContacts }: any, ref: any) => {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

    React.useImperativeHandle(
      ref,
      () => {
        return {
          onChange: handleChange,
        };
      },
      []
    );

    // @ts-ignore: next-line - Ignore event parameter on onChange
    const handleChange = (event, data) => {
      setChecked(!checked);

      setSelectedContacts((prevState: SelectedContactModel[]) =>
        data.checked
          ? [
              ...prevState,
              {
                key: contactKey,
                checked: data.checked,
                companyKey: contact.companyKey,
                companyName: contact.companyName,
                individual: contact.individual,
                title: contact.title,
                firstname: contact.firstname,
                surname: contact.surname,
                telephone: contact.telephone,
                mobile: contact.mobile,
                retired: contact.retired,
                address: contact.address,
                postcode: contact.postcode,
                email: contact.email,
              },
            ]
          : prevState.filter((contact) => contact.key !== contactKey)
      );
    };

    return (
      <div ref={ref}>
        <img src={contactIcon} alt="Contact Icon" />
        <div>
          <Checkbox
            labelPosition="after"
            label={`${contact.firstname} ${contact.surname}`}
            checked={selectedContacts.filter((contact: SelectedContactModel) => contact.key === contactKey).checked}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          {contact.email != "" ? <SecondaryText text={contact.email} /> : <></>}
          {contact.telephone != "" ? <TertiaryText text={contact.telephone} /> : <></>}
          {contact.mobile != "" ? <TertiaryText text={contact.mobile} /> : <></>}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const ContactText = React.forwardRef<{ onChange: (event: any, data: any) => void; scrollIntoViewOnClick: () => void }, HTMLDivElement>(({ contact, contactKey, selectedContacts, setSelectedContacts }, ref) => {
  React.useImperativeHandle((ref) => ({
    // You could name this whatever you want, we'll call it 'onChange'
    onChange: handleChange,
    // Just for the sake of this example and what 'useImperativeHandle' is used for
    scrollIntoViewOnClick: () => {
      // Logic to query for your div on the page and then scroll into view
      console.log('should scroll into view');
    }
  }));

  const handleChange = (event, data) => {
            setSelectedContacts((prevState: SelectedContactModel[]) =>
              data.checked
                ? [
                    ...prevState,
                    {
                      key: contactKey,
                      checked: data.checked,
                      companyKey: contact.companyKey,
                      companyName: contact.companyName,
                      individual: contact.individual,
                      title: contact.title,
                      firstname: contact.firstname,
                      surname: contact.surname,
                      telephone: contact.telephone,
                      mobile: contact.mobile,
                      retired: contact.retired,
                      address: contact.address,
                      postcode: contact.postcode,
                      email: contact.email,
                    },
                  ]
                : prevState.filter((contact) => contact.key !== contactKey)
            );
          };

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <img src={contactIcon} alt="Contact Icon" />
      <div>
        <Checkbox
          labelPosition="before"
          label={`${contact.firstname} ${contact.surname}`}
          checked={selectedContacts.filter((contact) => contact.key == contactKey).checked}
          //@ts-ignore - Ignore event parameter on onChange
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        {contact.email != "" ? <SecondaryText text={contact.email} /> : <></>}
        {contact.telephone != "" ? <TertiaryText text={contact.telephone} /> : <></>}
        {contact.mobile != "" ? <TertiaryText text={contact.mobile} /> : <></>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

`useImperativeHandle` enables you to expose methods that only you want to be available outside of your component.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a `onClick` etc on the `div` element and do what you do inside the `onChange` in the `Checkbox` (although you will need to compute `checked` like you do in the render), or you can just change the `<div>` into a `<label>` as clicking on a label will delegate the click to whichever `<input>` element it wraps (or has a `for` with a matching ID).

```
 const ContactText = ({ contact, contactKey, selectedContacts, setSelectedContacts }) => {
  return (
    <label> {/* <------------ */}
      <img src={contactIcon} alt="Contact Icon" />
      <div>
        <Checkbox
          labelPosition="before"
          label={`${contact.firstname} ${contact.surname}`}
          checked={selectedContacts.filter((contact) => contact.key == contactKey).checked}
          //@ts-ignore - Ignore event parameter on onChange
          onChange={(event, data) => {
            setSelectedContacts((prevState: SelectedContactModel[]) =>
              data.checked
                ? [
                    ...prevState,
                    {
                      key: contactKey,
                      checked: data.checked,
                      companyKey: contact.companyKey,
                      companyName: contact.companyName,
                      individual: contact.individual,
                      title: contact.title,
                      firstname: contact.firstname,
                      surname: contact.surname,
                      telephone: contact.telephone,
                      mobile: contact.mobile,
                      retired: contact.retired,
                      address: contact.address,
                      postcode: contact.postcode,
                      email: contact.email,
                    },
                  ]
                : prevState.filter((contact) => contact.key !== contactKey)
            );
          }}
        />
        {contact.email != "" ? <SecondaryText text={contact.email} /> : <></>}
        {contact.telephone != "" ? <TertiaryText text={contact.telephone} /> : <></>}
        {contact.mobile != "" ? <TertiaryText text={contact.mobile} /> : <></>}
      </div>
    </label>
  );
};
```